# How can I fill number format to whole column in excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

file format in column `A` is like `000000000050000402` but should be like `50000402` I can do it with this in VBA  `Range("A2").Value = CLng(Range("A2").Value)` what i want is to aply it to whole column but I dont know how.

Thanks for any help.

I am using Excel 2010

SOLVED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I have solution which works for me :-) but I want thanks to any body who wants to help me

```
    With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With

Set a = Range(("A2:A") & lastRow)
For Each b In a.Rows
   b.Value = CLng(b.Value)

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that I have used. This will convert the current active column to number when run:

```
Sub Conv_Col_To_No()
On Error Resume Next

    ' Take copy of a normal cell (taken from far right of sheet)
    Range("AAA1").Copy

    ' Paste special (add) to convert data in column to number
    Range(ActiveCell.Address, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Just checked further. This actually applies the number format to all cells on the current column for the current row onwards (i.e. any cells above the active cell will be left as they are).

Comment: Hi! at addr it says `Variable not defined`

Comment: It is defined in the line `addr = ActiveCell.Address` as long as you have an active cell selected this should work (for that column).

Comment: instead of addr I use only ActiveCell.Address
 and it worked thanks

Comment: great, I have cut the code down a little and posted an update.

Comment: On closer inspection I think you are right. For some reason the old version was running for me, but there was no dim statement for addr. Anyway, I have adjusted now to just use activeCell as you suggested.

Comment: Hi I have problem its look strange but your macro atcts strange the number `000000000050000402` should be like `50000402` but it is like `50022398` do you know why? Thanks for Answer

Comment: I have just tested the scenario with `000000000050000402` and various other numbers in text preceded by zeros. This seems to work fine for me. Do you have any value in the cell AAA1? I have used this in the code just to pick up an arbitrary unused field way off to the right, but if this had a value in it it could cause the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, for me not! My solution is good enough, but thanks anyway for try.